Need help with propagation of errors
Let $v_i$ and $u_i$ be measured data and noiseless data respectively, where $i \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$ denotes the $i^{th}$ realization of the random variables $v$ and $u$. The random variables $v$ and $u$ are dependent. The sample mean and standard deviation of $v_i$ and $u_i$ over $N$ realizations is given by,
\begin{equation}
    \bar{v} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} v_i, \quad\quad\quad \sigma_v = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (v_i - \bar{v})^2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \bar{u} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} u_i, \quad\quad\quad \sigma_u = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (u_i - \bar{u})^2}
\end{equation}
The standard errors $\sigma_{\bar{v}}$ and $\sigma_{\bar{u}}$ on means $\bar{v}$ and $\bar{u}$ respectively can be computed using,
\begin{equation}
    \sigma_{\bar{v}} = \frac{\sigma_v}{\sqrt{N}}, \quad\quad\quad   \sigma_{\bar{u}} = \frac{\sigma_u}{\sqrt{N}}
\end{equation}
The error between the means of the measured data and the noiseless data as a percentage of the noiseless data is given by,
\begin{equation}
e(\bar{v}, \bar{u}) = \bigg(\frac{\bar{v} - \bar{u}}{\bar{u}}\bigg) \%
\end{equation}
To compute the error in quantity $e(\bar{v}, \bar{u})$, we will use propagation of errors. Let $e(\bar{v}, \bar{u}) = \bar{w}/\bar{u}$, where $\bar{w} = \bar{v} - \bar{u}$.
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:sigma_e}
\sigma_e = |e| \sqrt{\Big(\frac{\sigma_{\bar{w}}}{\bar{w}}\Big)^2 + \Big(\frac{\sigma_{\bar{u}}}{\bar{u}}\Big)^2 - 2 \text{cov} (\bar{w}, \bar{u})}
\end{equation}
The quantities that need to be simplified further in the above equation are $\sigma_{\bar{w}}$ and $\text{cov}(\bar{w}, \bar{u})$. The term $\sigma_{\bar{w}}$ can be computed as,
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:sigma_w^2}
    \sigma_{\bar{w}}^2 = \sigma_{\bar{v}}^2 + \sigma_{\bar{u}}^2 - 2\text{cov}(\bar{v}, \bar{u}) 
\end{equation}
where $\text{cov}(\bar{v}, \bar{u})$ is,
\begin{equation}
    \text{cov}(\bar{v}, \bar{u}) = \mathbb{E}[(\bar{v} - \mathbb{E}[\bar{v}]) (\bar{u} - \mathbb{E}[\bar{u}])] = 0
\end{equation}
Question: Is the above expression correct? Can we compute covariance between two variables, when we have just one instances each of those variables? If so, this shows that although $v_i$ and $u_i$ are not independent, their means are $\bar{v}$ and $\bar{u}$ are independent. Please let me know of any errors in my thinking.
So, the term $\sigma_{\bar{w}}^2$ becomes,
\begin{equation}
    \sigma_{\bar{w}}^2 = \sigma_{\bar{v}}^2 + \sigma_{\bar{u}}^2
\end{equation}
Similarly, the term $\text{cov}(\bar{w}, \bar{u})$ can be computed as,
\begin{equation}
    \text{cov}(\bar{w}, \bar{u}) = \text{cov}(\bar{v} - \bar{u}, \bar{u}) = \text{cov}(\bar{v}, \bar{u}) - \text{cov}(\bar{u}, \bar{u}) = \text{cov}(\bar{v}, \bar{u}) - \sigma_{\bar{u}}^2 = - \sigma_{\bar{u}}^2
\end{equation}
And finally, $\sigma_e$ is given by,
\begin{equation}
    \sigma_e = \bigg|\frac{\bar{v} - \bar{u}}{\bar{u}}\bigg| \sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{\bar{v}}^2 + \sigma_{\bar{u}}^2}{(\bar{v} - \bar{u})^2} + \frac{\sigma_{\bar{u}}^2}{\bar{u}^2} + 2\sigma_{\bar{u}}^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\bigg|\frac{\bar{v} - \bar{u}}{\bar{u}}\bigg| \sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{v}^2 + \sigma_{u}^2}{(\bar{v} - \bar{u})^2} + \frac{\sigma_{u}^2}{\bar{u}^2} + 2\sigma_{u}^2} 
\end{equation}
